# Custom Loss in Keras from an external Python Function

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I would like to get my loss from an external source, so in my loss function, where the input data is a matrix of 0's, I reset it back to zero (yPred - yTrue - yPred) and then increase that 0 value by my true_loss, which is from my_function(x,y,z):

```
def lossFunction(yTrue,yPred):
    #x = output 1
    #y = output 2
    #z = output 3
    true_loss = my_function(x, y, z) #LOWER IS BETTER

    return K.mean(K.square(yPred - yTrue - yPred) + true_loss, axis=-1) #first part is always 0, plus our custom (true) loss
```

I need x, y, and z to be the outputs of the final layer (Dense Layer of 3 neurons) which are numbers, and then the function evaluates that set of numbers

The goal of the network is thus, to ignore the input data, and minimise the function my_function(...)

Is this possible? Since I noticed with a print, the lossFunction only executes once right at the start. A custom callback has the same issue since variables cannot be updated inside the loss function, and my_function will be dynamic since x, y, and z changes as the model evolves.

Thanks!

Comment: x=y_pred[0], y=y_pred[1],z=y_pred[2]?

Comment: Also : K.square(yPred-yTrue-yPred)=  K.square(yTrue); are you sure you meant this in the loss

Comment: Thanks for that, it’s just a dummy loss until I figure out how to do it. The issue is that I can only use x, y, and z once when then code executes, I need to pass them to a function each time to evaluate the loss - it’s a python function F(x,y,z)